# NLog Config - How to use a layout variable inside a CompoundLayout?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, logging, nlog

In my NLog Config I have a variable to hold my JsonLayout:

```
<variable name="jsonLayoutv0.1">
    <layout type="JsonLayout">
      <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />

    </layout>
  </variable>
```

I then want to place this layout inside a compoundLayout later on in my NLog config without having to re-write the whole jsonLayout again:

```
<sl:layout xsi:type="CompoundLayout">
    <layout xsi:type="SimpleLayout" text="@cee: " />
    <INSERT HERE/>
</sl:layout>
```

How can I go about re-using the variable inside a CompoundLayout?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog 5.0.1 is now available: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.0.1 so you can do this:

```xml
<nlog>
    <variable name='jsonLayoutv0.1'>
        <layout type='JsonLayout'>
          <attribute name='short_date' layout='${shortdate}' />
          <attribute name='message' layout='${message}' />
        </layout>
     </variable>
    <targets>
    <target name='compoundFile' type='File' fileName='log.txt'>
      <layout type='CompoundLayout'>
        <layout type='SimpleLayout' text='|Before| ' />
        <layout type='${jsonLayoutv0.1}' />
        <layout type='SimpleLayout' text=' |After|' />
      </layout>
    </target>
</nlog>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/4940